# no modifica me marca Undfined variable php

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy tratando de modificar un registro con php y me marca error

```
    <?php
include("conexion.php");

$id=$_REQUEST['ID'];

$name=$_POST['name'];
$district=$_POST['district'];
$population=$_POST['population'];

$query="UPDATE city SET Name='$name',District='$district',Population='$population' WHERE ID='$id'";

$result=$conexion->query($query);

if($result)
{
    echo "$query";
}
else
{
    echo "Fallo la modificacion";
}
```

Pero al dar clic en el botón modificar me aparecen errores en las variables como lo son:

```
    Undefined variable ID
    Undefined variable name
    Undefined variable district
    Undefined variable population
```

Cabe mencionar que ya tengo otra tabla en la cual hago la operación modificar con el mismo proceso y si modifica, esta tabla repite algunas variables como lo son "name" y "population".

Este es mi forumlario

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
            $id=$_REQUEST['ID'];

            include("conexion.php");

            $query="SELECT * FROM city WHERE ID='$id'";
            $result=$conexion->query($query);
            $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        ?>

        <form action="modifycity_process.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" metod="POST">
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row ['Name']; ?>" required><br/><br/>

            <label>District</label>
            <input type="text" name="district" placeholder="District" value="<?php echo $row ['District']; ?>" required><br/><br/>
            <label>Population</label>
            <input type="text" name="population" placeholder="Population" value="<?php echo $row ['Population']; ?>" required><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="Modify">

        </form>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primer paso: **depurar**. En este caso verifica los datos con un `var_dump($_POST);`, los mensajes indican que o el POST está vacío o las claves del mismo no se llaman cómo crees que se llaman. Depura y dinos cuál es el resultado.

Comment: parece que los POST esta vacio como soluciono esto

Comment: Tienes un error aquí: `metod="POST"` te falta una h que puede estar confundiendo las cosas, corrige: `method="POST"`

Comment: Parece que ya toma los valores, pero me queda el error en el id `undefined index ID in modifycity_process.php line 4`

Comment: Añade el resultado del `var_dump` a la pregunta para ver cómo llega ahora el POST. Y da uniformidad al código, no uses REQUEST por un lado y POST por otro, me refiero a esto: `$id=$_REQUEST['ID'];` cámbialo por esto: `$id=$_POST['ID'];` aunque, al pasar ese valor en la URL, quizá tengas que recuperarlo con `$_GET`... en fin, creo que tu código necesita ser mejorado, incluso, podrías pasar a usar Ajax, pero ese es otro asunto.

Comment: Ok me aparece ```'name' => string 'xxxx' (lenght 8) 'district' => string 'xxxx' (lenght 4)'population' => string 'xxxx' (lenght 6)'modify' => string 'Enviar' (lenght 6) UPDATE city SET Name='xxxx',District='xxxx',Population='xxxx' WHERE ID=''```

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_GET);`, al pasarlo en la URL el ID debe estar en el GET.

Comment: Perfecto ya funciona al 100, se me complica un poco esto ya que soy estudiante y estoy empezando a programar con php, muchas muchas gracias ha salvado mi materia jeje como puedo calificarlo en esta plataforma? ya que igual soy nuevo, de nuevo muchas muchas gracias :D

Comment: Ahora escribo una respuesta para que puedas aceptarla/calificarla. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que estás empezando con PHP, te daré una clave fundamental para PHP y para cualquier otro lenguaje, la cual te ahorrará horas/días rompiéndote la cabeza cuando algo falle: me refiero a **depurar**. Cuando tienes errores, depura los datos con los que estás trabajando. En PHP en concreto existe una función que se llama `var_dump`, que deberías usar provisionalmente cuando algo falla. En este caso, el primer paso sería hacer un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver si llegan datos y cómo llegan.

Dicho eso, que vale para cualquier lenguaje, con sus métodos propios de depuración, pasamos al problema. En el formulario, tienes una error de sintaxis, que es como si no indicaras ningún método, por lo tanto, el servidor no reconocerá los datos.

El error está aquí: `metod="POST"`. Falta una `h`, por tanto lo correcto sería: **`method="POST"`**

Luego, en PHP, estás usando `$_REQUEST` para acceder al `ID`, generalmente, los datos que son pasados en la URL, debes obtenerlos con `$_GET`, por tanto, deberías cambiar esto: `$id=$_REQUEST['ID'];` por esto: **`$id=$_GET['ID'];`**. En algunos contextos esto podría ser indiferente, no obstante, siempre es bueno conocer la diferencia de métodos y usar la super global adecuada.

En resumen:

- Si usas `method="post"`, usa la super global `$_POST` para recuperar todos los elementos que son parte del formulario.
- Si pasas datos en la URL, usa `$_GET` para recuperar esos datos.